# Can this cell numeric value be "displayed" in a different way in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

Take a cell with this numeric value `210061`.

I would like to display this cell as:

> 21.0.6.1

Specifically:

- The first 2 digits are the major value.
- The next two digits are the minor value (but stripped of leading zeroes).
- The fifth digit is a build value (0 to 9).
- The last (sixth) digit is a beta value (0 to 9)

Comment: There is no way to store the value in the cell as a number and have it show the way you want using just number formats. A formula in another cell could do it easily, though. Two options are `=MID(A1,1,2)&"."&TEXT(MID(A1,3,2),"0")&"."&MID(A1,5,1)&"."&MID(A1,6,1)` if you like the consistency of using `MID()` for each part or `=LEFT(A1,2)&"."&TEXT(MID(A1,3,2),"0")&"."&MID(A1,5,1)&"."&RIGHT(A1)` if you prefer the most direct functions.

Comment: @EngineerToast Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

*=LEFT(A1,2)&"."&TEXT(MID(A1,3,2),0)&"."&MID(A1,5,1)&"."&MID(A1,6,1)*

[image]